# Lua How to remove apostrophe(s) from string

Tags: lua

So I am having a issue with Lua gsub removing apostrophes from strings if there is one apostrophe on its own or loads of them i can't seem to get it to remove any of them.

```
local uri_without_args = "'" --one on its own
local uri_without_args = "''''''''lol''''" --in text
local uri_without_args = "''''''''''''" --loads
--etc--etc all occurrences must go

local list = {
"%'", --apostrophe
}
for k,v in ipairs(list) do
    local uri_without_args_remove_duplicates, occurrences = uri_without_args:gsub(""..v.."","")
    if occurrences > 0 then
    occurrences = occurrences + 1
        for i=1, occurrences do
            if uri_without_args_remove_duplicates=="" then
                --do nothing
            else
                uri_without_args = uri_without_args:gsub(""..v.."","")
            end
        end
    end
end


print(uri_without_args)
```

Comment: You variable `uri_without_args_remove_duplicates` contains correct result, but you neither saved it nor printed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time you assign a new value to `uri_without_args` is when `uri_without_args_remove_duplicates` is not empty. If you either remove the `if` statement from around the assignment to `uri_without_args`, or if `uri_without_args` starts off as `"''''''''lol''''"`, then it works fine.

As Egor said in the comment, you also could simply use `uri_without_args_remove_duplicates` as the result value.

Comment: i removed the if statement as recommended and it works fine now thank you :)